# How to write a Prometheus exporter that collects values in a file?

Tags: python, prometheus, monitoring, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

Let's say I have a file that is used to keep track of the state of devices that are plugged into a computer. The file looks like this:

```
DEVICE_1 = ONLINE
DEVICE_2 = OFFLINE
DEVICE_3 = ONLINE
DEVICE_4 = OFFLINE
```

How can I use the [prometheus_client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python) Python library to create a custom exporter that would scrape the values in that file? I plan to display the values in a time series graph using Grafana so I can see how the state of each device changes over time. Would I need to use a Histogram or a Gauge? It's important that I keep the device id and its state together. Could someone explain the best approach so that they could be converted to a metric?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 questions here, what metric type to use for this data, and how to use the client library.

I am going to answer the metric type question. I define "best" as creating a graph like below that will cycle between 1/0 when the device is ONLINE/OFFLINE:
[image: boolean gauge]

I would implement a gauge that is either a 1/0. A histogram adds complexity, and samples observations. It can be used to track the rate devices were removed, ie DEVICE1 is removed/plugged in X times in the last 60 minutes.

In your python exporter app, parse your file and use labels to specify the values for each device

```
g = Gauge('customapp_activedevices', 'Description of gauge')

while True:
    file= open("devicefile", "r")
    deviceCollection = file.read()

    for device in deviceCollection:
        if device.status == 'ONLINE':
            metricVal = 1
        else:
            metricVal = 2
       g.labels(devicename=device).set(metricVal)
```

Then your grafana query is pretty simple, because those labels will become different series in your graph. You would also set the Instance label in your exporter, so your grafana dashboard could handle multiple instances of your exporter, and multiple devices.

[image: grafan query]

Comment: Thanks for replying! This is the exact solution that I arrived at as well actually. However there is one problem. Every time I change the state of a device in the file. Say DEVICE_1 = OFFLINE. It will show up as a completely new metric and Grafana displays the 2 states (online, offline) of DEVICE_1 twice on the dashboard . Do you know of anyway so I can show the metric just once and how its changing over time?

Comment: Wait never mind. I was able to figure out my issue. I was adding a second label to my metric that kept track of the state and this is what was leading it to create an entirely separate metric. What Brandon did above works correctly. Just use 1 label that's static and you know wont change. This will prevent it from creating another metric. Thanks again!

Comment: @atlee19 can you pls share the complete exporter code, Thanks